# Which mode does allow a stable connection between Bluetooth Low Energy and Android phone?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have two options for a connection between BLE and the Android Phone:

```
connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback); // If We want to directly connect to the device
connectGatt(this, true, mGattCallback); // If We want to automatically connect (in background) to the device
```

I tested both methods: the first one is more faster connection but it does not allow reconnecting in background. However, in this question, I regard to stable connection. Which one is more stable in two methods? If I want more stable connection, could you suggest to me the method to do it? Thank all

This is my full code

```
public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }

        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Call connect function");
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
        // parameter to false.

        //mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
        new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (device != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connect connectGatt");
                    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), true, mGattCallback);
                }
            }
        });

        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with autoConnect = true. Then you won't need to do anything to reconnect if it disconnects and it will retry forever to keep the connection alive. You must however listen for bluetooth state change and reconnect when bluetooth has been restarted. Just be aware of this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69834.

You will however never get a 100% stable BLE connection due to bugs in both Android's code and also a lot of many Bluetooth chip manufacturer's code inside the Bluetooth controllers.

Comment: Thanks. But I test with both options and autoConnect=false looks more stable. I do not know it is correct or not.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you mean with more stable? One the connection is up and running the stability of that particular connection does not depend on whether autoConnect was used or not.

Comment: Sorry for delay reply. Stable connection means it will maintain the connection until I call disconnect function. However, in my case, I connected the BLE device, about 3 second, it automatically disconnect (just for some time)